# Solve for $x$ when $4^{x-1} + 4^{x-3} = 272$

Tags: exponential-function

$$4^{x-1} + 4^{x-3} = 272$$

I've tried to check if I can convert it to a logarithm but found there's not an answer ($x \in \mathbb Z$), and I'm not sure how to continue from there.

Thanks in advance for any help you provide.

Comment: Factor out a $4^x$

Comment: Somehow, I missed something this obvious. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: We can factor $4^{x-1}+4^{x-3} = 4^2 \cdot 4^{x-3}+4^{x-3} = (4^2+1) \cdot 4^{x-3} = 17 \cdot 4^{x-3}$.

Also, $272$ is divisible by $17$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $u=4^{x-1}$ and rewrite the equation as $u+\frac{u}{16}=272\to\frac{17u}{16}=272$ so $u=256\implies 4^{x-1}=256\implies x=5$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$4^{x-1} + 4^{x-3} = 16 (4)^{x-3} + 4^{x-3} =17 (4)^{x-3} = 272$$